# Location of image folder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

i want to add an image for my menu    `item.Image.Url = "~/Images/BO_Users_Large.png";

when can i creat folder image and put the image BO_Users_Large.png

and this is the code of the menu :

```
 @Html.DevExpress().Menu(settings => {
           settings.Name = "HeaderMenu";
           settings.ItemAutoWidth = false;
           settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
           settings.Styles.Style.Border.BorderWidth = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(0);
           settings.Styles.Style.Paddings.Padding = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(0);
           settings.Items.Add("Client");
           settings.Items.Add(item =>
           {
               item.Items.Add("Liste des clients").NavigateUrl = DevExpressHelper.GetUrl(new { Controller = "Client", Action = "ListeClients" });
               item.Items.Add("Ajouter Nouveau client").NavigateUrl = DevExpressHelper.GetUrl(new { Controller = "Client", Action = "Ajouter" });
               item.Text = "Client";
               item.Image.Url = "~/Images/BO_Users_Large.png";

           });
           settings.Items.Add(item =>
           {
               item.Text = "Home";
               item.Image.Url = "~/Images/ButtonHome.png";
               item.Items.Add("News");
               item.Items.Add("Contact Us");

       }).GetHtml()
```

Comment: yes you have to create one folder inside your project and drop your file there. it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your image in the folder content or create another folder in your project and put this code :

```
settings.Items.Add(item =>
{
    item.Text = "Commande";
    item.Image.Url = "~/content/BO_Reports_Large.png";    
});
```